# Tracking form submissions in SquareSpace using GTM

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics, squarespace

I'm helping a friend setting up a site on SquareSpace. I've set up Google Tag Manager (GTM) to automatically track form submissions and link clicks (using Auto Listener).

However, the forms in SquareSpace does not work with the Form Listener in GTM (apparently due to use of return false in the onSubmit handler in the code, see https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/tag-manager/Vlro87_GOVY)

I've been trying for hours and hours to find another way to make this work (I'm pretty n00b when it comes to JS, I'm afraid, but I'm trying my best).

I also tried to implement the code mentioned in this answer: http://answers.squarespace.com/questions/7450/how-can-i-track-form-submissions-in-google-analytics in my footer, without any events showing up in GA. It should be noted that I use Universal Analytics, not the old GA - and hence do not use the GA field in SquareSpace, as that only support the old Google Analytics. The GA code is added to my site through Google Tag Manager (GTM).

Does anyone know a workaround? For example can I add some custom JS code to trigger after the form is submitted, that will send data to GTM through my DataLayer?

Please note that in SquareSpace you cannot change the code for the form itself (that would have made things much easier), but you can add some html that will be loaded after the form is submitted.

This is what I've tried so far:

1) adding the following to my footer section

```
<!-- Form Submit tracking -->
<script>
  Y.use('node', function() {
    Y.on('domready', function() {
      Y.all('.form-block').each(function(n) {
        var d = n.getData('block-json');
        d = Y.JSON.parse(d);
        n.one('form').on('submit',function() {
         _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', d.formName + ' Submission', 'Form Submission', 'Submit']);
        });
      });
    });
  });
</script>
<!-- Form Submit Tracking END -->
```

2) adding this to the footer:

```
<!-- Form Submit tracking -->
<script>
  Y.use('node', function() {
    Y.on('domready', function() {
      Y.all('.form-block').each(function(n) {
        var d = n.getData('block-json');
        d = Y.JSON.parse(d);
        n.one('form').on('submit',function() {
           dataLayer.push({
             'label': 'Get The Bundle',
             'action': 'Submit',
             'event': 'SS Form Submit'
           });
        });
      });
    });
  });
</script>
<!-- Form Submit Tracking END -->
```

3) adding this code to the custom HTML field after a form is submitted:

```
  <script onload="loadGTM()">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function loadGTM() {
        dataLayer.push({
            'label': 'Get The Bundle',
            'action': 'Submit',
            'event': 'SS Form Submit'
          });
       }
    </script>
```

I really hope someone could help point me in the right direction. I'm sure there must be other people trying to do similar things that would benefit from this as well.

Thanks! :)

Comment: What macros, rules, and tags have you set up in GTM? Just adding the code above will not fire a GA event; it will only fire a GTM event.

Comment: Yes, it will fire a GTM event, which you then need to configure GTM so it fires a GTM Tag to GA so that GA knows what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

That is good.

Now in GTM, listen for the event via a Trigger. And then create a GTM Tag to publish the Trigger to GA.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question, but it is closest to the problem I was having. Maybe this will help someone else out in the future.

### TL;DR:

If you're wanting to execute a dataLayer.push for a GTM event (or any JS, for that matter) in a Form Block post submission, you'll need an element with an onload property in the Post-Submit html.

Here's what I ended up with

```html
<object onload="window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []; dataLayer.push({ 'event': '[Your event name here]', });" 
   data="data:text/html, <div style='opacity: 0; font-size: 1px; color: #ffffff;'>the form has submitted</div>"
   style="width: 0px; height: 0px;" />
```

The data and style properties of this object aren't important, I just did it to ensure the object would load.

It's a stupid work around, but it does seem to work.

The alternative would be to change the forms Post-Submit to a Redirect that would take the user to a "Thank you for your submission" page that would run the JS for a dataLayer push on page load.

### Background:

Some time early 2023, the Form Block was updated to outright ignore script tags *[(here's a forum post surrounding that)](https://forum.squarespace.com/topic/243174-form-post-submit-javascript-suddenly-stopped-working/?do=findComment&comment=630634)*.

This means if you wanted to do a dataLayer.push in the Post-Submit html -- something as simple as this:

```
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  dataLayer.push({ 'event': '[Your event name here]', });
</script>
```

The Post-Submit will ignore it.

What it seemingly won't ignore (for now ) is an onload script, hence the above solution.